# How to ask apply to return dataframe instead of series

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply a function that takes 4 values and returns two values, and use this to fill two columns in a dataframe.

```
def gendata():
    for a in (0,1,NAN):
        for b in (0,1,NAN):
            for c in (0,1,NAN):
                yield a,b,c
values = list(gendata())
index = np.arange(len(values))+999
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["a","b","c"], index=index)
```

makes:

```
        a    b    c
999   0.0  0.0  0.0
1000  0.0  0.0  1.0
1001  0.0  0.0  NaN
...
```

Picking two columns and applying on a function returning a list with two elements gives me a dataframe with two columns:

```
def f2to2(x):
    a,b = x
    return [a+b, a*b]

result = df[["a", "b"]].apply(f2to2, axis=1)
print result
        a    b
999   0.0  0.0
1000  0.0  0.0
1001  0.0  0.0
```

This can be assigned into a dataframe like so:

```
df[['x','y']] = result
```

But picking four columns and applying on a function returning a list with two elements gives me a Series of object:

```
def f4to2(x):
    lpos, lneg, rpos, rneg = x
    return [lpos+lneg, rpos+rneg]

print df[["a", "b", "c", "a"]].apply(f4to2, axis=1)
999     [0.0, 0.0]
1000    [0.0, 1.0]
1001    [0.0, nan]
...
dtype: object
```

and the following fails

```
df[['x','y']] = result
```

because result is a single series where two are required for the assignment.

Why does applying f4to2 give me a series, but f2to2 give me a dataframe and in general how can I know whether a series or dataframe will be returned?

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is silent about this.

Comment: Now, that is interesting.  Pass two columns it returns a dataframe, pass in four columns it returns a series.  You can force a f4to2 to return a dataframe by `return pd.Series([lpos+lneg, rpos+rneg])`

Comment: Yeah, but that gives me very many series (one per row). I want to get out just two.

Comment: I got back a dataframe with two columns, that you could assign to columns 'x','y' from f4to2 when I wrapped the return with pd.Series.

Comment: Yes, but it constructs 2M  series objects for 1M rows.